# How to read input values from / apply CSS to popout window

Tags: javascript

I have a popout window, which I would like to apply CSS from a separate file to.

I also need to read user input from the inputs in the popout, and have it apply to the non-popout section.

Here is what I have so far

```
  popout = () => {
    let doc = window.open('', '', 'width=1200,height=800').document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(document.getElementById("test").outerHTML);
    doc.close();
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v3pdzLka/13/

In the case of this fiddle, I would like the button color to transfer over to the popout, as well as have the input from the popout write to the original input.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways..

```
let doc = window.open('', '', 'width=1200,height=800').document;
doc.open();
doc.write(`<p>big butt so what</p>`);

// style property
doc.body.style.background = 'purple';

// inline styles
var styles = doc.createElement('style');
styles.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(`
  p{ color: green; }
`));
doc.head.appendChild(styles);

// stylesheet
var link = doc.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('href', 'mystylesheet.css');
doc.head.appendChild(link);

doc.close();
```

forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fyugnj91/

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas about the input part though? Maybe a save button that copies over the values?

Comment: @Grambam that wasn't part of your question if you accept my answer and ask a new question i'd be happy to take a look.